# exe referencing in batch files

Tags: file, batch-file, reference

I am beginning to learn the delights of batch files but need some help in trying to find a method for using a batch file to run a program within a folder, the batch file will be immediately outside the folder, the location of the batch file and folder will vary (though both together in the same relative positions) as they will be distributed.
I could find no previous questions on this and am hoping that there is a way. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`%~dp0` is the location of your batch file.  So you'd do:

```
%~dp0\some_directory\exe_name.exe
```